# Perturbation theory: Why is the inner product expressed as $\langle\psi_m^0|H'|\psi_n^0\rangle=-2V_0(-1)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, linear-algebra

Introducing a perturbation to an unperturbed state, say $\psi_n^0$, with eigenenergy $E_n^0$ yields the first degenerate state as:

$$\psi_n^1=\sum_{m\neq n}\frac{\langle\psi_m^0|H'|\psi_n^0\rangle}{(E_n^0-E_m^0)}\psi_m^0$$

And the perturbation $\psi_1^1$ yields:

$$\psi_1^1=\sum_{m\neq 1}\frac{\langle\psi_m^0|H'|\psi_1^0\rangle}{(E_1^0-E_m^0)}\psi_m^0\tag{1}$$

Now defining the perturbed Hamiltonian as $H'=V_0 a\delta(x-\frac{a}{2})$ using the common $\delta$-function we get the that the first perturbed eigenenergies must be $E_n^1=2V, \; n$ even$, \; 0$ otherwise. For even $n$ we have $\psi_n^0(\frac{a}{2})=0$ and the perturbation is not noticed. Now; what confuses me is that the solutions to this exercise define the numerator of eq. 1 as:

$$\langle\psi_m^0|H'|\psi_1^0\rangle=-2V_0(-1)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}$$

Which makes sense for uneven values of $m>1$, but if the values of $m>1$ are even, we receive complex values of the inner product. Why is this the case? If we have $\psi_n^0(\frac{a}{2})=0$ should we not have that the inner product vanishes? What do these complex inner-product values express?

Comment: The value $\langle\psi_m^0|H'|\psi_1^0\rangle$ itself, especially the phase factor, is not particularly meaningful since one can always absorb it into the definition of the state $|\psi_m^0\rangle$, for $m\neq 1$.

Comment: Okay, but what implies that it is there? The state $\psi_n^0(\frac{a}{2})=0$ does not tell us that there exists complex valued inner products.